# Echidna: test contract balance

Tags: solidity, testing, slither, echidna

Is it possible to send funds to an Echnidna fuzzing contract before the tests start? For example, if I wanted to test for `address(this).balance != 0` as an invariant, how would I seed to contract with coins ahead of time?

```
contract MyContractFuzz is MyContract {
    function echidna_test_balance() public view returns (bool) {
        return (address(this).balance != 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, create a config file, e.g. echidna.yaml and add the following:

```
#balanceContract overrides balanceAddr for the contract address
balanceContract: 0
```

You might also want to play around with this, but I don't think it's necessary.

```
# #balanceAddr is default balance for addresses
# balanceAddr: 0xffffffff
```

Remember to change your constructor to `payable`, otherwise the constructor will fail, and to pass in the config, e.g. `echidna-test . --config echidna.yaml`.

Here's a link to the [default config](https://github.com/crytic/echidna/blob/master/tests/solidity/basic/default.yaml).